# Differentiating both sides of an inequality

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $I = [0, +\infty)$ and let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function on $I$ such that there exists a constant $M \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $$f'(x) \le M,\ \forall x \in I$$
>   Prove that $$f(x) \le Mx + f(0),\ \forall x \in I$$

I'm not sure how should I approach this problem. I can intuitively understand what should be proven and why it is so, but I don't know where to start.

I also noticed that the conclusion would be immediately reached if I differentiated both sides of the inequality. However, I'm not sure I can do that safely (i.e. avoiding to turn a truth into a falsehood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Check that the function $\phi:I\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $\phi(x)=f(x)-Mx-f(0)$ is differentiable and compute its derivative.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! So $\phi(x)$ is differentiable as it is a composition of differentiable functions. Then $\phi'(x) = f'(x) - M$, which is always negative by hypothesis. Then $\phi(x)$ is decreasing on $I$. But I'm stuck again as I still need that $f(0) < M$ to conclude the proof.

Comment: No, you don't need this inequality. Since $\phi$ is decreasing, for every $x\geq 0$, $\phi(x)\leq \phi(0)$. What is $\phi(0)$ ?

Comment: Oh perfect. Thank you very much!